# li and a element styling issue with Chrome after clicking a link

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

I have a simple menu that works fine in Firefox, but when using Chrome the links move around when you click on them and so it breaks the styling. I read from somewhere that `display: block;` on `a` element would fix this, but it didn't.

You can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/dewg1L8y/1/
Use Chrome and click the links to see what I mean.

Also any idea how to remove the text wrapping in Chrome? It stays on one line in Firefox.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">second link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Move your padding from the `a` to `li`.

Comment: This certainly helps, but what if I need to change the background of the li element on hover? I need that padding there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the padding from 10% to 10px or more for the a tag

Comment: it is because, from browser to browser, the units may create a problem.

keeping paddings and margins in px is always a safe side

Comment: I think I got my answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

in your css change to have 
    li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    }
    a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

this will still display inline and the style will stay the same whatever the browser